# Mapbox Android Annotations Plugin for Android

Tags: mapbox-android

I have had some experience with Mapbox maps for android, handling various annotations such as Markers, Polylines etc. However, with the new API v7, Mapbox encourages developers to use the new Annotations Plugin because the previous annotations classes are deprecated. 
My question is how are the classes in this new plugin, specifically the Symbol, Line and Fill used with SymbolLayers, LineLayers and FillLayers? Are these both needed to draw an annotation on the map or can we use these interchangeably?